# How to add html table rows n times using ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**I've to create 'n' no. of table rows, where 'n' will be selected from dropdown list. Following is my dropdown list**

```
<select class="form-control" name="custemitype" ng-model="emi_type">
 <option>Select</option>
 <option>12</option>
 <option>24</option>
 <option>36</option>
 <option>46</option>
 <option>60</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please note the downvotes are likely due to a complete lack of effort from your side. Please read [ask] - you will likelz need https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**app content:**

```
angular.module('ngrepeatSelect', [])
 .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.data = {
    emi_type: null,
    options: [
      {id: '1', value: 'Select'},
      {id: '2', value: 12},
      {id: '3', value: 24},
      {id: '4', value: 36},
      {id: '5', value: 48},//is it really 46?
      {id: '6', value: 60}
    ]
   };
}]);
```

**html content:**

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="myForm">
    <label for="custemitype"> Repeat select: </label>
    <select name="custemitype" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="data.model">
      <option ng-repeat="option in data.options" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.value}}</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <tt>model = {{data.model}}</tt><br/>
</div>
```